# Error: Missing Right Parenthesis when Creating Index on Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am trying to create a table with an index but it's causing an ORA-00907 error which says I am missing a right parentheses. Here is my example sql that causes the error.

```
create table example
(
   id number(12, 0) not null using index (create index example_idx on example(id))
);
```

Perhaps it is because of the not null keywords but I don't understand why it asks a right parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`create table`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_7002.htm) and [`create index`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_5012.htm) are separate statements, you can't mix them like that (although you can have an index implicitly or explicitly created to back up a unique or primary key constraint you define in-line).

You need to do this in two steps, as two separate statements:

```
create table example (id number(12, 0) not null);
create index example_idx on example(id);
```

---

The example you show from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/indexes003.htm):

```
CREATE TABLE a (
 a1 INT PRIMARY KEY USING INDEX (create index ai on a (a1)));
```

is in a section titled 'Specifying the Index Associated with a Constraint', and 
is creating the index as part of a primary key constraint. The `using index` clause is described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_7002.htm#sthref5311).

In your code you are created a not-null constraint, which is not backed by an index, so that clause is not valid here. You can only use this method of creating an index if it is to back a unique or primary key, as the link you provided says.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/indexes003.htm
This link shows the same way (see Example 1).

Comment: @randacun - it does, but only for unique and primary key constraints, and you are not creating one of those; only a not-null constraint. I've updated the answer to hopefully clarify that.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably stick with declaring the index separately.